# Not able to find the element using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this following html section:

```
<div class="clearfix tac">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-inr rupee_symbol_visibility"></i> </span>
        <input type="text" id="bid" name="bid" class="form-control" value="180000000" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="height: 40px;width: 140px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Since `id` and `name` have same value("bid"), I am not able to find the element by id/name.

I used following method:

```
uname = mydriver.find_element_by_id("bid")
```

But no success. Can someone suggest any method?

Comment: I don't see any element with an id of `id`.  Did you mean `bid`?

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Yes I meant `bid`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the element has `bid` as both its name and id.  What result do you get back from the `find_element_by_id` call?  Do you get an error, or just no results found?  Is there more than one element with that id?

Comment: I am getting: `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that element is present on the page?  Try printing out the page content and look at it to make sure.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is frequently due to the element being contained in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Can you show us the full HTML or URL of your application?